# Последовательность по возрастанию

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Компилировал код, вроде работает, но нужен совет по задаче, правильно оформлен ли код, а то есть сомнения? И еще массив использовать нельзя.

> В три переменные a, b и c явно записаны программистом три целых попарно неравных между собой числа. Создать программу, которая переставит числа в переменных таким образом, чтобы при выводе на экран последовательность a, b и c оказалась строго возрастающей.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        int a = 3;
        int b = -1;
        int c = 9;
        int x;
        switch
        System.out.println("Числа в переменных a, b и c : " + a  + " " + b + " " + c);
        if (a > b) {
            x = a;
            a = b;
            b = x;
        }
        if (b > c) {
            x = b;
            b = c;
            c = x;
        }
        System.out.println("Возрастающая последовательность: " + a  + " " + b + " " + c);
    }
}
```

Еще такой вопрос, как можно это реализовать с оператором switch?

Comment: @turtles Используйте метку учебное-задание для учебных вопросов.

Comment: А оператор switch тут вообще не причем. Он в сравнении участвует, когда есть ответ (переменная) и поиск, что делать при данном ответе (список возможных ответов и команды).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нельзя использовать массив? есть другие классы для хранения набора данных:

```
  final List < Integer > list = new LinkedList < Integer > ();
  list.add ( Integer.valueOf ( 3 ) );
  list.add ( Integer.valueOf ( 15 ) );
  list.add ( Integer.valueOf ( 9 ) );

  Collections.sort ( list );

  //System.out.println (list);
  for ( final Integer num : list )
  {
     System.out.println ( num );
  }
```

выводит в консоль:

```
3
9
15
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае, как я и говорил, не один раз надо проверку сделать, а 2 раза то есть будет

```
if (a > b) {
    x = a; a = b; b = x;
}
if (b > c) {
    x = b; b = c; c = x; 
}
```

и снова строка

```
if (a > b) {
    x = a; a = b; b = x;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Grimon

Comment: @turtles Кликните по галочке под ладошкой вниз слева от вопроса, если он вам помог.

Comment: Спасибо все тема закрыта нашел ответ на свой вопрос!